# Why is chicory added to coffee beans while grinding?

Tags: coffee-blends

In south India, we used to add chicory to our coffee. In the UK, I have not seen this blend of coffee anywhere. Is there a reason why South India adds chicory?

Comment: Not sure about blends, but Prewetts makes ground chicory. Maybe you could purchase some and mix it to taste with your favorite coffee?

Answer (score 8):

Chicory was added to coffee in order to stretch the supply of coffee because it was in short supply and expensive. Though it doesn't taste exactly like brewed coffee, chicory has a similar flavor profile and for some the flavor is complementary. Today, chicory use is predominately due tradition, as is the case here in Louisiana where many, especially in the more southern region of the state, prefer their coffee include chicory.

Comment: Absolutely! I'm actually from the midwest, but enjoy the slightly bolder flavor of chicory coffee. So I guess I'm one of those that thinks it complements the flavor.

Comment: @RatchetCity : Thanks for that. I got answer why chicory was initially added to coffee now. regards

Answer (score 0):

Probably, chicory was added to extend the supply of coffee but now it is getting added as a flavor. There are Indian brands that sell both varieties, with chicory and without chicory.